# How does a security group sid differ from a per service Sid?

Tags: sql-server

I am learning SQL and trying to understand the concept of a SID.

At the link below it states:

> Microsoft SQL Server uses a security group to set resource access
>   control lists (ACLs) instead of using the service account directly.
>   Therefore, changing the service account can be done without having to
>   repeat the resource ACL process. The **security group can be** a local
>   security group, a domain security group, **or a service security
>   identifier (SID)**

and then goes on to say

> For stand-alone instances of SQL Server on Windows Vista and on
>   Windows Server 2008 operating systems, **service SIDs are added to the
>   service group**, and the service SID for SQL Server Engine and SQL
>   Server Agent is added as a login to the sysadmin server role.

It uses service group and security group interchangeably. Are they the same? ...and linked to this, if a service SID can be added to a security group (which can also be a SID), these 2 SIDs are different right?

I think so, but struggling with the Microsoft documentation.

thanks.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2620201

Answer (score 1):

A SID is a mechanism that assigns privileges to the service itself, rather than to the account under which the service runs.

**For Clustered installations**:

It enables you to use a domain account with minimal privileges on the box, which also improves your security because people end up knowing the domain service
account credentials.

**For non-clustered installations**:

Per-Service SID, it allows you to use Network Service as the service account, improving security by
getting automatic password management, but without the traditional downside of having Network Service accumulate excessive privileges from multiple services.

Refer to :

- [SQL & SIDs why we need it and what the hell is it?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlpfeil/archive/2012/02/16/sql-amp-sids-why-we-need-it-and-what-the-hell-it-is.aspx)
- [SIDs and IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403629.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks. So a SID can be added to the security group (which contains the appropriate permissions) for that service. In the first paragraph of my post it says a security group can also be a SID? I don't understand how a SID can be added to a SID?

Comment: The language is a bit loose.  A Per-Service SID is not a "security group".  But it is kind-of like a "security group": it is the thing to which the permissions are applied, and which is separate from the service account.  And a running service inherits permissions granted to the Per-Service SID just like it inherits permissions granted to local or domain security groups.